# Why I can not remove all?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
private void retirerUnAnimalDeListe(int idxtoRemove)
{
    var new_animal = new Animal();
    my_animal[idxtoRemove] = new_animal;
    for (int i = 0; i < cont_animal; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(i + "\t");
        Console.Write("{0   , -10}", my_animal[i].m_type + "\t");
        Console.Write("{0   , -10}", my_animal[i].m_name + "\t");
        Console.Write("{0   , -10}", Convert.ToString(my_animal[i].m_age + "\t"));
        Console.Write("{0   , -10}", Convert.ToString(my_animal[i].m_poids + "\t"));
        Console.Write("{0   , -10}", my_animal[i].m_color + "\t");
        Console.Write("{0   , -10}", my_animal[i].m_owner + "\t");
    }
    var tolist = my_animal.ToList();
    tolist.RemoveAt(idxtoRemove);// //why my indes is not delete all ? tnx 
}
```

It produces this result on the screen:

[image]

Why do I have the extra row with the `1` header, and how can I remove/fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre] that we can paste into our editor and reproduce your issue.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question here. You're calling the `RemoveAt` method, which will only remove 1 item at the specified index. Are you expecting it to remove all the elements? Also, you're making a copy of the list and then removing it from the copy, the original collection is not touched, perhaps this is the bug?

Comment: tnx ffor respond me, i would like to remove all element of  my index that i  chose  ?

Comment: Please note that an array cannot be resized in-place in .NET. You can create a new array and replace the reference to your existing array with a reference to the new array, but a 2-element array in .NET will always have 2 elements. I believe the issue here is that you're using an array to store your animal objects, and you constructed a list with a copy of its contents in order to find a delete-method. You should switch your main collection to be a list instead of an array.

Comment: Hope this helps: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6ht5Kd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has two problems:

1. It only replaces the object for one with empty or null strings in the fields, and doesn't actually remove anything until **after** it prints the contents of the array.
2. When it does try to remove the item, it copies the references to a temporary list, removes the item from the list, and then throws the list away. The array remains unchanged.

If you need to be able to remove elements, use a `List<Animal>` instead of an `Animal[]` in the first place.

---

Finally, I strongly suggest adding a `ToString()` override to the `Animal` type that looks like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{m_type,-10}\t{m_name,-10}\t{m_age,-10}\t{m_poids,-10}\t{m_color,-10}\t{m_owner,-10}";
}
```

And then you can use it in the loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cont_animal; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i}\t{my_animal[i]});
}
```

Comment: Additionally, it would be a good idea to move  the loop for printing animals to a separate printAnimals function and not in the removeAnimalFromTheList function ( if poor French skills got that right  )

Comment: hehe your french is good :) tnx